# Problem in the definition of a different layout style for the examples in a document

Tags: formatting, enumerate, examples

I'm writing a document in which I defined a structure for the example in order to automatically enumerate them.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
\textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
   \section{One}
text...
\begin{example}
this is the first example
\end{example}

\section{Two}
text...
\begin{example}
this is the second example. The data are the following:

    A(${t}_{1}$): first line \\
    A(${t}_{2}$): second line \\
    A(${t}_{3}$): third line\\
    A(${t}_{4}$): fourth line\\
    \end{example}   

    \end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. the numeration of the example rebegin for each section but I want that it continue for all document.
2. In the example the first line ( A(${t}_{1}$)) of the second example is moved to the right with respect to the rows below. I would positioning all the rows vertically aligned.

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 6, you have

```
\newcounter{example}[section]
```

Remove `[section]` or comment it out (add `%` before it), it's what restarts the counter when a new section starts.

About the indenting example, just add `\noindent` before it, like:

```
\noindent
    A(${t}_{1}$): first line \\
```

[image: example image]

By the way, you can alternatively load the `amsthm` package which creates examples by default without you having to set a counter. It has different counters though, and you might have to read the manual to customize it.